# R: manipulate multiple files in a folder and combine

Tags: r, loops, file

I have a folder in which I have many .csv files that I want to first, a) manipulate, and b) add together in a way that each file is going to turn into a new row in the new file
See an example file that I have below. All others have the same format:

```
data <- structure(list(view_history = c("[{\"page_index\":0,\"viewing_time\":3078.7250000284985},{\"page_index\":1,\"viewing_time\":1287.8200000268407}]", 
                                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rt = c("4367.33", "32741.89", "84982.255", 
                                                                    "44164.12", "16395.195", "21816.545"), trial_type = c("instructions", 
                                                                                                                          "html-button-response", "survey-multi-choice", "survey-multi-choice", 
                                                                                                                          "survey-multi-choice", "survey-multi-choice"), trial_index = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         1, 2, 3, 4, 5), time_elapsed = c(4369, 37115, 122101, 166268, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          182665, 204484), internal_node_id = c("0.0-0.0", "0.0-1.0", "0.0-2.0", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "0.0-3.0", "0.0-4.0", "0.0-5.0"), stimulus = c(NA, "The price of hourly piano course has a mean of $100 with a standard devation of $20. Random samples are taken from the population from small to large sample sizes.</br><img src='LLI_wrong.png' style= 'width:25%; height:30%'><img src= 'LLI_graph_2.png' style= 'width:25%; height:30%'> <br/><img src= 'LLI_wrong2.png' style= 'width:25%; height:30%'><img src= 'LLI_wrong3.png' style= 'width:25%; height:30%'>", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA), button_pressed = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA), responses = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA, "{\"WQ2\":\"<strong>B.</strong> You should go to the large office.\"}", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "{\"WQ3\":\"<strong>B.</strong> The number of days on which mean heights were over 71 inches would be greater for the large post office than for the small post office.\"}", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "{\"WQ4\":\"<strong>B.</strong> The large street\"}", "{\"R2\":\"<strong>A. </strong> As the sample size increases, its mean will tend to be closer to that of the population\"}"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), question_order = c(NA, NA, "[0]", "[0]", "[0]", "[0]"), correct_response = c(NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), accuracy = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), key_press = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Next, I'm organizing and manipulating this data:

```
#keep only the related columns 
data2 <- select(data, time_elapsed, button_pressed, responses, accuracy)
#add time on task
data3 <- mutate(data2, time = tail(time_elapsed, 1))
#data shrunk + time on task added 
transformed_data <- select(data3, -time_elapsed)
#select the necessary cells and turn the data into a vector 
new_data <- c(transformed_data$button_pressed[2], transformed_data$responses[3:6], 
              transformed_data$button_pressed[7], transformed_data$time[1])
```

Next, I transpose the data and write it to a csv file:

```
new_data <- t(new_data)
write.csv(as.data.frame(new_data), "hello_data.csv")
```

What I want to do next and that I couldn't figure out:

Loop this process through all .csv files in the folder in a way that each row in your new file corresponds to the data from one file.

Comment: This setp `#select the necessary cells and turn the data into a vector` is it going to be same for each file ? How are you selecting those cells ?

Answer (score 0):

Get all the files from the folder with `list.files`

```
files <- list.files(path = "/path/to/folder", pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Then loop over the `files` and read the files

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- map_dfr(files, ~ {
    transformed_data <- readr::read_csv(.x) %>%
          dplyr::select(time_elapsed, button_pressed, responses, accuracy) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(time = time_elapsed[n()], time_elapsed = NULL)
    new_data <- as.data.frame(list(transformed_data$button_pressed[2], transformed_data$responses[3:6], 
              transformed_data$button_pressed[7], transformed_data$time[1]))
     
    new_data
    })
readr::write_csv(out, "hello_data.csv")
```

Comment: thank you but the output is different than what I want to. This produces a seperate csv for each file.

Comment: @gokgok I though you want to apply the code on each file and write separately

Comment: Try the updated code

Comment: @gokgok Do you get any error with the `out <- map_dfr(files, ~ {
    transformed_data <- readr::read_csv(.x) %>%
          dplyr::select(time_elapsed, button_pressed, responses, accuracy) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(time = time_elapsed[n()], time_elapsed = NULL)
    new_data <- as.data.frame(list(transformed_data$button_pressed[2], transformed_data$responses[3:6], 
              transformed_data$button_pressed[7], transformed_data$time[1]))
     
    new_data
    })`

Comment: It is your own code, which I passed into the loop

Comment: Ok, now it writes, but it doesn't write correctly for some reason. It doesn't take the same position of cells from each data.

Comment: I've got the error message:   Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 2, 11, 6, 8